# How to scale data but in reference of another chosen value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a list which I need to scale, for example:

> `[[45724.25]  [45570.08]  [45584.31]  [45549.79]]`

By using the **MinMaxScaler** of sklearn `from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler`, the data will be converted in values of 0 to 1, with 1 being the highest value of the list I want to scale and the rest of the values referencing that highest value.

How can I choose the value I want referenced. PX. scale my values referencing 100000, so the values will be scaled but with 100000 being the max value.

So instead of my scaled values being this:

> `[[1.]  [0.92]  [0.94]  [0.91]]`

turned into this:

> `[[0.47]  [0.43]  [0.45]  [0.41]]`

*px. the scaled values are not precise, they are here for more clarity.*

I thought (as wrote the question), that I could simply add the max value I want referenced in the original list:

from

```
[[45724.25]  [45570.08]  [45584.31]  [45549.79]]
```

to

```
[[45724.25]  [45570.08]  [45584.31]  [45549.79]  [100000.]]
```

use the scaler and then discard the inserted value.

The problem is that it will require additional processing on the data on my behalf, is there an easier way?

Comment: While I agree with DB82XL answer. I want to add that the function you reference `MinMaxScaler`, has two attributes which dictates min and max respectively. 0 and 1 is merely its default values.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kosmos mentioned, `MinMaxScaler` has a `feature_range` parameter, whose default is `(0,1)`. You can achieve the desired result by calculating what the new max value would have been given your reference value:

```py
# x is the raw data, c is the reference maximum to which the data should be references
x = np.array([[45724.25], [45570.08], [45584.31], [45549.79]])
c = 100000
print(f'Unscaled:\n{x}\n')

# Original approach: add max reference to dataset, scale, then drop
x2 = np.array([*x, [c]])
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x2)
x_scaled = x_scaled[:-1]
print(f'Scaled (original approach):\n{x_scaled}\n')

# Proposed approach: calculate the desired max based on c and provide custom range
# np.ptp returns the range of the array (max - min)
desired_max = np.ptp(x) / (c - np.min(x))
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, desired_max))
x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)
print(f'Scaled (custom max):\n{x_scaled}\n')
```

Output:

```
Unscaled:
[[45724.25]
 [45570.08]
 [45584.31]
 [45549.79]]

Scaled (original approach):
[[0.00320403]
 [0.00037263]
 [0.00063397]
 [0.        ]]

Scaled (custom max):
[[0.00320403]
 [0.00037263]
 [0.00063397]
 [0.        ]]
```

Comment: That is not what I am asking, I want to know how to reference all data as max value of 100k, as you see in the second scale of the answer.